# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column XYZ sorting GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to add a **sorting function** to a column in a **GridView**.

I've set the **AllowSorting-property** on the GridView to **true** and added **sort expression** to the column.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="doName" HeaderText="doName" SortExpression="doName" />
```

Unfortunately, the sorting isn't working in the GridView.

Below is my **code-behind-file** for the column that should be able to sort, but I get the error:

> Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column
>   doName.

**Code behind:**

```
string sortingDirection;
DataSet dsProducts = new DataSet();
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

public SortDirection dir
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["dirState"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["dirState"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        }
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["dirState"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["dirState"] = value;
    }
}

public string SortField
{
    get
    {
        return (string)ViewState["SortField"] ?? "doName";
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["SortField"] = value;
    }
}

protected void gvProducts_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{

    sortingDirection = string.Empty;
    if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Descending;
        sortingDirection = "Desc";
    }
    else
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
        sortingDirection = "Asc";
    }


    DataView sortedView = new DataView(dt1);
    sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortingDirection;
    SortField = e.SortExpression;
    gvProducts.DataSource = sortedView;
    gvProducts.DataBind();
}

protected void gvProducts_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{       
    if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        sortingDirection = "Asc";
    }
    else
    {
        sortingDirection = "Desc";
    }

    DataView sortedView = new DataView(dt1);
    sortedView.Sort = SortField + " " + sortingDirection;
    gvProducts.DataSource = sortedView;
    gvProducts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gvProducts.DataBind();
}

private void BindData()
{
    gvProducts.DataSource = RetrieveProducts();
    gvProducts.DataBind();
}

private DataSet RetrieveProducts()
{
    sql = "Select * from doTable;";

    dsProducts = new DataSet();

    using (OdbcConnection cn =
      new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();

        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {

            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dsProducts);

            dt1 = new DataTable();
            dsProducts.Tables.Add(dt1);
        }
    }

    return dsProducts;
}
```

Comment: Your code behind looks like it's one class. It's confusing and I don't know why you have properties for SortDirection and what not in it?!

Answer (score 3):

This exception occured because in `gvProducts_PageIndexChanging` method, value of `dt1` has been reset to new `DataTable()`, it doesn't have any rows or columns.

So you have to reload value of `dt1.`

Change you code as follow.

```
OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(dsProducts);

if (dsProducts.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    dt1 = dsProducts.Tables[0];
}

dtProducts = dt1;

-------------------------------------------

protected void gvProducts_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    sortingDirection = string.Empty;
    if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Descending;
        sortingDirection = "Desc";
    }
    else
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
        sortingDirection = "Asc";
    }

    BindData();
    DataView sortedView = new DataView(dt1);
    sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortingDirection;
    SortField = e.SortExpression;
    gvProducts.DataSource = sortedView;
    gvProducts.DataBind();
}
```